# Arrow Keys, TextField focus in java?

Tags: java, jtextfield, arrow-keys

I have a `JPanel` with 16 `JTextfield` (4x4) in it, I draw them using for loop.

Now, I want to use my arrow keys to move focus from this jtextfield to the other.

How can I do that?

**Code** *(edit extracted from OP's answer)*

```
private JTextField[] characters;

public void drawWords() {
pnlWords.removeAll();
pnlWords.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
characters = new JTextField[4 * 4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4 * 4; i++) {
    characters[i] = new JTextField();
    characters[i].setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    characters[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    characters[i].setFont(font);
    characters[i].addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            charactersKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });
    pnlWords.add(characters[i]);
}
}


public void charactersKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
int key = evt.getKeyCode();        
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 * 4; i++) {
        switch (key) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                characters[i - 1].requestFocus();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                characters[i + 1].requestFocus();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                characters[i - 4].requestFocus();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                characters[i + 4].requestFocus();
                break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Try adding a KeyListener

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of all of your JTextFields and a KeyAdapter to your panel. If the entered key is the right key, set the focus to the next JTextField in the array. If it's the left key, set the focus to the previous JTextField. Consider the difference between preincrement and postincrement in this.

Comment: could you give me an example please, I have done it this way but I must be wrong somewhere so it isn't work. Thank you

Comment: What have you got so far? Post a pastebin link/github link. Me providing you with the code won't help you but improving yours will. Of course, if you don't want me to do that, just tell me.

Comment: No, of course I want to improve myself. My code is above

Comment: OK. The majority of what you have is correct, just a few tiny mistakes. Use an index field to track the current index rather than your for loop identifier. Try changing keyTyped() to keyPressed(). It's what I used. If that does not work, I have created a gist for you https://gist.github.com/Injustice/11186371